# What's the latest version of Boot Camp Assistant that can be installed on Snow Leopard?

Tags: snow-leopard, bootcamp, windows

And also, where do I download it? Currently it says Boot Camp Assistant is version 3.0.4. And Software Update says everything is already up to date but I see some people say they have version 3.3 on Snow Leopard so yeah I'm rather confused.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple Insider says](http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/08/24/apple_updates_boot_camp_3_3_imac_firmware) 3.3 update if for people using Boot Camp 3.1, maybe that's why.

Did you try [downloading it](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1443?viewlocale=fr_FR) directly from Apple's website ?

Comment: But that one you linked is a .exe, isn't it supposed to be a .dmg or .pkg? I can get the latest Boot Camp support software for Windows but the one confusing me is the OS X side, the `Boot Camp Assistant.app` in Utilities folder.

Comment: BootCamp is mostly a package of Windows drivers, the Assistant is just a tool the create a partition.

Answer (score 1):

To get bootcamp related software and drivers best is to put the SnowLeopard Installation disk in the drive.

1. From the "**Go**" menu pick "**Go to Folder…**" and type "**/Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ Install\ DVD/System/Installation/Packages/**"
2. Then double click "**BootCamp.pkg**"
3. Run "**Software Update …**" from the Apple menu afterwards

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3777

Note iMac 27-inch users may have a black screen after Windows 7 installation. The fastest way I have found to get rid of this issue and install drivers is to delete "**Windows\system32\drivers\atikmpag.sys**" this can either be done from Windows CLI using the Windows installation disc or by installing Paragon NTFS, Tuxera or else on OS X.

You may also opt for rEFIt http://refit.sourceforge.net if you want to boot on more systems than an OS X and a Windows.